# Didn't get values from mysql when more than one data frame inserting in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read xlsx file from unread mail and convert it  to data frame finally it will insert into MySQL DB.To avoid duplication while inserting each row of data frame i check if the data already present in db,for this duplication i check mails one by one.

My issue is when two or more unread mail is present in inbox this duplication check fails.

```
detach_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + 
'/attachments'
user = "abc@outlook.in"
pwd = "xyz@123*"


m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
m.login(user,pwd)

# Select the mailbox
m.select("folder name in mail")
n = 0

resp, items = m.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

    if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()

     df_mail = pd.read_excel(att_path,skiprows= 
   [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],skip_blank_lines=True,skipfooter=1,index=False)
     df_mail = df_mail.fillna(0)
     df_mail.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)

     for i, row in df_mail.iterrows():
         sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tablename WHERE condition for duplicate'
         extist=con.execute(sql)

         duplicate=extist.fetchall()

         if len(duplicate) == 0:

             df_mail.iloc[i:i+1].to_sql('table', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000,index=False)

         else:
            print("duplicate data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code and a list of things you have tried? It is very hard to help without those.